# Android: Navigation Drawer not starting detail activity

Tags: android, android-activity, navigation-drawer

My manifest file is like this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.test.navigationdrawer" >
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".DetailActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_detail"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
            <!-- The meta-data element is needed for versions lower than 4.1 -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".MainActivity" />
            >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and the code I am using to start the DetailActivity from MainActivity is

```
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, DetailActivity.class);
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
// Adds the back stack
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(DetailActivity.class);
// Adds the Intent to the top of the stack
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
// Gets a PendingIntent containing the entire back stack
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        builder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(1, builder.build());
```

Comment: ....wait, so are you trying to make a notification that will start the detail activity?

Comment: no error message, I am just trying to start detailactivity from home view of navigation drawer so the back button on the action bar becomes visible when detailactivity shows up as mentioned here http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/navigation.html